# Grub option pci=noaer does not appear to work

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 and, as with many other people, I am getting repeated AER messages in my log.  These are correctable and related to the Broadcom LSI SAS3008 serial attached SCSI.

Looking at many other postings, I see that one option is to turn off the AER messages via the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter in the /etc/default/grub file.  I have set this to "quiet splash pci=noaer".

However, I still get these annoying error messages. Is there some way at runtime to determine if the noaer flag is really set to true? Any idea why these messages still appear even when I've told the kernel not to generate them?

Thanks.